# angularjs I need to print all page in paged ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I need to print (send to printer) all 100 element in my paged ng-repeat
while I display 20 element in the page

I tried to use AngularPrint but it didn't work because it print only one page

any idea please?

this is my code

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr class="info">
                    <th ng-click="sort('client')" class="col-md-1" rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                        Klant
                        <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='client'" 
                              ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="col-md-2" colspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                        Total
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('difference')" class="col-md-1" rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                        Difference
                        <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='difference'" 
                              ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('percentage')" class="col-md-1" rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                        Difference %
                        <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='percentage'" 
                              ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="info">
                    <th ng-click="sort('firstYear')" class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                        {{ criteria.firstYear }}
                        <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='firstYear'" 
                              ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                    </th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('secondYear')" class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                        {{ criteria.secondYear }}
                        <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='secondYear'" 
                              ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="searchable">
                <tr ng-repeat="stat in stats | orderBy:sortKey:reverse" ng-class="stat.total1 >= stat.total2 ? 'danger-row':'success-row'">
                    <td>{{ stat.companyAbbrev }}</td>
                    <td class="td-right">&euro; {{ stat.total1 | number : 2}}</td>
                    <td class="td-right">&euro; {{ stat.total2 | number : 2 }}</td>
                    <td class="td-right">{{ stat.difference | number : 2 }}</td>
                    <td class="td-right">{{ stat.percentage| number : 2 }} %</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure but this sounds like a grid of elements?  What are you using for your grid?  I know that [AngularUI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/) has print and export to excel capabilities and a lot of supporting documentation.  It can also be a little bit daunting to implement due to it's scope.

To answer your comment in regards to print functionality check this link: [exporting data tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data)  When you click the menu button in the example and select export to pdf it opens up the pdf in a separate browser tab that you can save or print.

Comment: Ok so I see you opted to make your own grid using glyphicons and angular.  This works well from a flexibility standpoint but sometimes it's good to leverage other solutions that all ready figured this stuff out.  What I see here seems like a good fit for Angular UI Grid.  Given that it appears you aren't doing editable grid stuff the refactoring shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: I can refactor my code but I want to be sure to find soluation to my problem, what is the soluation to use so I can print the complete grid?